# Sum of inverse of Fermat's numbers

Tags: number-theory

What is the sum of inverse of all Fermat's numbers?
I know the series is convergent using comparison by geometric series with common ratio 1/2 and first term 1/2 but I don't know how to find the sum?

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure we are not able to relate it to any known constants with our current knowleadge.

Comment: See [OEIS A$051158$](http://oeis.org/A051158).